# SwiftGen "Killed: 9" at startup because "Code Signature Invalid", but only if installed via Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur, swiftgen

I installed the latest (6.4.0, October 2020) version of [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) via Homebrew on a new MacBook Pro M1 running Big Sur (11.1), but every time I try to run it, it's killed, and the console says that it's because `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)`.

**The 6.4.0 binary downloaded straight from [the GitHub release page](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/releases/tag/6.4.0) works.** This sounds like there's a problem with the Homebrew version.

- Who is responsible for fixing the Homebrew version?
- I can replace the Homebred-installed one (at `/usr/bin/local/swiftgen`) with the downloaded binary, but the download also contains a number of frameworks and stencils. Where those should be copied to?

The relevant console bits are:

```
Process:               swiftgen [94658]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/swiftgen/6.4.0/bin/swiftgen
Identifier:            swiftgen
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [562]
Responsible:           Terminal [498]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-03-04 23:01:01.231 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        foo

Sleep/Wake UUID:       bar

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        Unknown

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x0000000100bb0000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2

kernel messages:

Backtrace not available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the second part of my question. The unzipped files need to be copied to `/usr/local/Cellar/swiftgen/6.4.0`.